# How to detect defect/missing pills in blister pack? (Matlab)

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

How do I detect defect/missing tablets in the tablet strips. Assuming there is one missing tablet in the tablet strip. I've tried `stdfilt()`, but the image contains alot noise .I ve also tried average and median filtring such as canny and prewitt. I also added noise such as salt and paper to the image.
Is there any othe segmentation method? Any coding will be helpful

[image]

```
I2=rgb2gray(I);
J = imnoise(I2,'salt & pepper',0.02);
figure
imshow(J)
Kaverage = filter2(fspecial('average',3),J)/255;
figure
imshow(Kaverage)
Kmedian = medfilt2(J);
imshowpair(Kaverage,Kmedian,'montage')
BW1 = edge(Kmedian,'Canny');
BW2 = edge(Kmedian,'Prewitt');`
```

Comment: I'd detect circles to assign the position of the tablets, the look at the  intensity histogram of each location and see what portion of the dark crescent the missing pills has. Based on that I'd use a threshold if there is or isn't a pill.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an approach based on my comment

```
% reduce to grayscale
d=rgb2gray(your_img);

% find edge and blur a bit so we can find circles
d2=conv2(edge(d),ones(9),'same');
d2=max(d2(:))-d2;

% find circles
Rmin = 71; Rmax = 80;
[center, radius] = imfindcircles(d2,[Rmin Rmax],'Sensitivity',0.98);

% Display what we found  
imagesc(d);axis square
hold on;
viscircles(center,radius);
plot(center(:,1),center(:,2),'yx','LineWidth',2);
hold off;
```

[image]

```
% histogram of each circle content:
[x, y]=meshgrid(1:size(d,2),1:size(d,1));

for n=1:numel(radius)

    circle_pixels{n}=find ((x-center(n,1)).^2+(y-center(n,2)).^2<=radius(n).^2);
    h(:,n) = histcounts(d(circle_pixels{n}),0:max(d(:)) );

    subplot(2,5,n); plot(h(:,n));title(['circle # ' num2str(n)]);
end
```

[image]

Now  we can see how the intensity is distributed in each circle and choose a metric to discriminate the missing pills. We can see that for the missing pills (#5,#9,#10) we have a less simple distribution of intensities (more than one peak) , and in particular a saturation of the maximal intensity that happen because of the glare reflection of the foil probably.  So you can choose now a threshold based on that, or any other statistical metric you want (# of peaks in the distributions etc)...