# Calculating the histogram value inside circles (houghcircles)

Tags: python, histogram, masking, opencv, hough-transform

I have been trying to convert this matlab code [How to detect defect/missing pills in blister pack? (Matlab)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65617434/how-to-detect-defect-missing-pills-in-blister-pack-matlab)  into python, and I have been stuck on this issue for a while.
I am trying to find the histogram values inside the hough circles detected in my image. I tried applying a mask for every circle detected and calculate the hist values inside those masks,  but I am getting hist values as zero. when I tried displaying the mask using

```
masked_img = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)
cv2.imshow("Masked", masked_img)
```

at the end of the code, the window shows a black screen

My full code is shown below

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
pills = cv2.imread('pill6.jpg').astype('uint8')
gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(pills, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img = cv2.medianBlur(gray_img,  5)
cimg = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

#applying the hough circle transform
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 70, param1=100, param2=30, minRadius=40, maxRadius=60)
circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
for i in circles[0, :]:
#draw the outer circle
    cv2.circle(pills, (i[0], i[1]), i[2], (0, 255, 0), 6)

#applying the mask
    for indexx, ch in enumerate(pills):
     mask = np.zeros(img.shape[:2], dtype="uint8")
     cv2.circle(mask, (i[0], i[1]), i[2], (0, 255, 0), 6)
     hist_item = cv2.calcHist([pills], [0], mask, [255], [0, 255])
     print(max(hist_item))
cv2.imshow("HoughCirlces", pills)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The image of pill6:
[image: pill6]

Comment: Please provide the image `pill6.jpg`

Comment: @TomMcLean The image of pill6 has been added